# Can't resolve Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777

Tags: vagrant, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am having this problem when trying to issue vagrant up or even vagrant ssh on windows linux subsystem and I can't resolve it.
I already tried to put

```
chmod go-w /mnt/c
```

with

```
[automount]
options="metadata,umask=0033"
```

in the etc/wsl.conf file that I had to create by my own.
I didnt find other options in the internet.
Can someone help me?

Comment: You probably need to explain more about what you are trying to do.  It is very unlikely someone will fully understand the context of your question without further explanation.

Comment: This appears to be more of a general software question. I would recommend asking this [with more detail](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam I am trying to run vagrant up. And this on the title of  the topic occurs.

Comment: @Jesse I asked there.